# Approximating Subdivision Surfaces with Gregory Patches

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, mesh

In the paper from Charles Loop, et. al, on approximating catmull-clark subdivision with Gregory patches here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/SGA09.pdf

... the paper shows how to compute edge points like so:

[image]

However, I was confused as to how to compute these (in red):

[image]

I tried reading through the source code of Pixar's OpenSubdiv only to find that they've evolved far beyond this paper, yet I have an academic/toy interest in understanding the original paper and technique.

Could someone with a background on this subject (or a superior ability to digest such papers) help me to understand how to compute these terms? The jackpot would be someone who has already implemented this technique in code, but that may be tough to find.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that the red marked things are vectors? I am not very deep in that subdivision field, but usually vectors called e are the unit vectors to create your coordinate system (This might be not mathematically correct denoted.). So, e_0^- should be the vector which looks along the negative x axis and so on. Here is a table to help you with that:
e_0^+ -> pos. x axis, 
e_0^- -> neg. x axis, 
e_1^+ -> pos. y axis, 
e_1^- -> neg. y axis, 
e_2^+ -> pos. z axis, 
e_2^- -> neg. z axis. I am not sure whether this helps you, but I hope so.

Comment: @DanceIgel Yes, all of the terms in there are vectors -- actually representing points in 3d space.

Comment: Ok. The table is not formatted as table, but I hope that it will help you anyways.

Comment: @DanceIgel Many thanks! I think that might help me somehow to digest the paper. I've always been really slow at understanding and implementing papers -- weak on the mathematical background and even understanding of some of the conventions of mathematicians (I find pseudocode so much easier, e.g.). I will try to also print out a copy of this PDF -- flip through it and try to see what I missed.

Comment: If there is the need to and you are very new to the field of subdivision, I can provide the slides of a lecture I visited dealing with subdivision surfaces.

Comment: @DanceIgel Much appreciated! I'm actually somewhat seasoned there as an implementor but my background tends to be in implementing Doo-Sabin, CC, Loop, polar subdivision -- those types of recursive schemes which can be easily described in a page of pseudo-code -- without understanding the deep theoretical side to it. Also don't have a very deep background in splines and patches, even though the theoretical side of subdivision surfaces springs from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98204/discussion-between-danceigel-and-ike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself. The paper is not terribly clear about this and assumes that the reader is able to infer the meaning of **q** by its definition. If we look at this definition

[image]

It turns out that **q** is relative to which starting index is chosen for **m**_i (and also **c**_i). It might have been better to give an additional index to **q**_j such that

[image]

For a vertex with valency n there would be n such **q**_j. In this way all tangent vectors form an affine n-gon.